# Нужна помощь по HTML(формы)

Tags: html, css, checkbox, html-form, radio

В форме, при наведении курсора на поля checkbox и radio, должна
вокруг этих полей появляться прерывистая рамка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.checkbox-container,
.radiobutton-container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 2px;
}

.checkbox-container:hover,
.radiobutton-container:hover {
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  <label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
</div>

<div class="radiobutton-container">
  <input type="radio" id="radio" />
  <label for="radio">Radiobutton</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!

Comment: @HenadzKuryliuk Если вам помог мой ответ, то отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.radiobox, .checkbox {width: 200px;padding 5px;border:1px dotted transparent}
.radiobox:hover, .checkbox:hover {border-color:black}
```

```html
<div class="radiobox">
  <input type="radio" id="radio">
  <label for="radio">text</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check">text</label>
</div>
```

Comment: div должен быть лейблом. А как сейчас - это жесть - рамка есть, а клик праве текста не срабатывает.